# FWrite in new line

Tags: php, fwrite

Trying to make my form inputs to be written in data.txt file.
I want it to write in new line each time someone registers.
Tried to use .PHP-EOL but it doesn't seem to add any new line after each entry!

```
<?php
 $path = 'data.txt';
 if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['country']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $fh = fopen($path,"a+");
    $string = $_POST['firstname'].' - '.$_POST['country'].' - '.$_POST['email'] .PHP_EOL;
    fwrite($fh,$string); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
 }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$string = $_POST['firstname']." - ".$_POST['country']." - ".$_POST['email'] ."\r\n";`?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work aswell. I now found my solution and used PHP_EOL at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Exactly what you could have found in the solution of the link we have provided above. This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work!

Use PHP_EOL at the beginning instead of the end.

Here is the code now:

```
<?php
 $path = 'data.txt';
 if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['country']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $fh = fopen($path,"a+");
    $string = PHP_EOL .$_POST['firstname'].' - '.$_POST['country'].' - '.$_POST['email'];
    fwrite($fh,$string); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
 }
?>
```